# Not able to use built-in models i.e. "user", error: no response from server

Tags: mysql, server, response, loopbackjs, built-in

I have created many models in loopback for my project. And use these models with the help of "http://localhost:3000/explorer" in my browser.

These model API's are working fine. But, whenever I tried to use built-in models i.e "user" from the explorer. I got the below error:

[image: "error": "no response from server"]

and in the terminal. I got the below error. And terminal command **automatically terminates**.

[image: throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors TypeError: roleModel.isInRole is not a function]

I am new in the loopback. Why am I not able to use built-in models "user".

Please, help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this with LB version 3?

Comment: @Raymond Camden  "$ npm ls loopback " 
loopback@3.17.1  ,

"$ lb --version "
4.1.0 (generator-loopback@5.5.0 loopback-workspace@4.0.0)

Comment: Any chance you can zip up your models and share them? Did you make any other changes? I'm not able to reproduce this.

Comment: Oh, lb --version is for the CLI. It isn't for the app. When you made your app using the CLI, what version did you pick? The default is 3.

Comment: I have selected version 3.

Comment: Hmm well Im not sure. Is the only thing you've changed models? If so, could you zip them and send them to me?

Comment: I have sent my project to your mail.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else that encounters this, I ran into this today and found this question unanswered, so I will do my best to give my explanation and findings here.

The error, `roleModel.isInRole is not a function`, means simply that the role model does not have a function called `isInRole`.

In my case, this was because another model was automatically generated from an existing database table called Role, which overrode the internal Role model of `Loopback`.

When the internal Role model is overridden, the isInRole function is not inherited automatically and will result in the above error.